# How to Subtract Time between two Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on an event system and would like to know how to get the range of time available to schedule. I have the following tables

#### Table1 (To record the availability of creating events)

```
| Date          | Start Time      | Final Time  |
| ------------- |: -------------: | ----------- |
| 2019-02-01    | 09:00:00        | 12:00:00    |
| 2019-02-01    | 13:00:00        | 17:00:00    |
```

and then I have Table2 to properly record the events, taking into account the availability in Table1. Table2 and Table1 have the same fields. An example of the records in Table 2 would be the following:

#### Table2

```
| Date          | Start Time      | Final Time  |
| ------------- |: -------------: | ----------- |
| 2019-02-01    | 08:00:00        | 11:00:00    |
| 2019-02-01    | 13:00:00        | 14:30:00    |
```

The specific question is: **What would be the SQL query to be able to determine what are the remaining time ranges, available from Table1 with respect to those that have already been taken or set out in Table2.**

**I'm using Laravel but I can not get the exact SQL query that works for me in this case.**

I would like to get this result:

```
| Date          | Start Time      | Final Time  |
| ------------- |: -------------: | ----------- |
| 2019-02-01    | 08:00:00        | 09:00:00    |
| 2019-02-01    | 11:00:00        | 12:00:00    |
| 2019-02-01    | 14:30:00        | 17:00:00    |
```

I hope I was clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it was me, I'd store date and time as a single entity

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your desired result.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks for your time, I did it

Comment: You *can* achieve this with a single SQL query, but it would very complex. It's much simpler to combine PHP code with a few SQL queries. Have you tried anything in that direction?